# Debug dart-sdk with Xcode but get Assembler

Tags: xcode, dart

I'm trying to debug dart-sdk and learn how it works in Xcode. But setting breakpoints at source code doesn't work(the program just don't stop). I wrote an endless loop and it stopped, giving me the assembly code. And I tried to set breakpoint in assembly code, which also worked. See the code below.

```
dart`dart::bin::main:
->  0x100002940 <+0>:    pushq  %rbp
0x100002941 <+1>:    movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x100002944 <+4>:    pushq  %r15
0x100002946 <+6>:    pushq  %r14
0x100002948 <+8>:    pushq  %r13
0x10000294a <+10>:   pushq  %r12
0x10000294c <+12>:   pushq  %rbx
0x10000294d <+13>:   subq   $0xb8, %rsp
0x100002954 <+20>:   movq   %rsi, %r15
0x100002957 <+23>:   movl   %edi, %r14d
0x10000295a <+26>:   leal   0xa(%r14), %r12d`
```

If I want to debug the source code, I can only use lldb in the command line. But is there any way that I can debug dart-sdk in Xcode?

My **always show disassembly** has turned off.